# INSERT INTO Compare tables from 2 databases

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert

I am looking to compare 2 tables from 2 databases on the same server and insert that data into a 3rd table. I thought this would be easy but am not sure how to do this with 2 databases. The code below is not liked by SQL Server. Any help would be great.

```
INSERT INTO WaterAccounts (CaseNumberKey, MASTER_ACCOUNT, 
                            OWNER_NAME, MAIL_NAME, ACCT_BALANCE)
   SELECT 
      B.CaseNumberKey, 
      C.MASTER_ACCOUNT, 
      C.OWNER_NAME, 
      C.MAIL_NAME, 
      C.ACCT_BALANCE
   FROM 
      newCityCollection.PropertyInformation B, DEM C
   WHERE 
      B.Name = C.SERV_STREET 
      AND B.DIRECTION = C.SERV_DIRECTION 
      AND B.NUM = C.SERV_STREET_NO
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Comment: `newCityCollection` is this your schema name?

Comment: If databases are on the same server and your user is permitted to use it, only need to add database name before schema name. In this case (using database name) schema name is required. The rest is the same as if you used the tables in a single database

Comment: @marc_s well blame microsoft.  All their sample code is what is above just as Aaron Bertrand states in the article.  I have no issues doing it either way but in this case the result will be the same so the point is moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `newCityCollection` is the other database, and `PropertyInformation` the table in it, you're missing the schema name. Assuming it's `dbo` (probably is), you shoud write something like this:

```
   INSERT INTO WaterAccounts (CaseNumberKey, MASTER_ACCOUNT, OWNER_NAME, MAIL_NAME, ACCT_BALANCE)
   SELECT 
      B.CaseNumberKey, C.MASTER_ACCOUNT, C.OWNER_NAME, 
      C.MAIL_NAME, C.ACCT_BALANCE
   FROM newCityCollection.dbo.PropertyInformation B
   INNER JOIN DEM C
      ON B.Name = C.SERV_STREET 
        AND B.DIRECTION = C.SERV_DIRECTION 
        AND B.NUM = C.SERV_STREET_NO
```